# ppa for ubuntu-packaged mariadb-10.4 for ubuntu 16.04 xenial

Tags: 16.04, ppa, mariadb

Is there a ppa or other repo providing ubuntu-style packages of mariadb 10.4 for ubuntu 16.04?

I'm trying to easily get some vms upgraded from mariadb-10.0 (server and client).

Comment: Did you follow instructions given in https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-package-repository-setup-and-usage/ ?

Comment: @dariofac I believe those mariadb packages don't have the debian/ubuntu customizations that the existing xenial mariadb-10.0 packages I'm using have, and would be more work to configure and install.  I will fall back to those, but was hoping for something more seamless first

Comment: @dariofac ah, that's different than what I initially tried (https://mariadb.org/download "Respository Configuration tool") and seems to be working.   thanks

Comment: I'll add it as answer, please mark it as accepted if working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MariaDB provides a package repository which includes packages for Ubuntu Xenial, as stated [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-package-repository-setup-and-usage/).

To add the repository, open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and execute:

```
curl -LsS https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb_repo_setup | sudo bash -s -- --mariadb-server-version mariadb-10.4
```

The script requires `curl`, `ca-certificates` and `apt-transport-https` (which can be installed by executing `sudo apt install <package>` replacing `<package>` with the actual package name).